# QGIS 3, iterate shapefiles to export mulitple pdfs from a standalone python script

Tags: qgis, pdf, qgis-3, standalone, python-3

I would like to load my qgis project, and a template I made into my stand alone script (in pycharm).

I have a folder with shapefiles and I would like to iterate over them, plot each one with the same symbology. Then export each map to a pdf.

I unfortunately have found very little on how to do this even in Qgis 2, and especially cannot figure it out with Qgis 3.

I have my qgis and pyqt5 paths working fine in pycharm, just don't know what to do next, or where to find info.